# How to stop a @Bean annotated Kstream kafka consumer and continue to run spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have multiple @Bean annotated Kstream , kafka consumers in same class , once a particular message (K,V) pair is consumed by all consumers , I need to stop all the consumer and execute a separate piece of code.The //comment part is what I need .
Below is pseudo-code for one of the consumers :

```
 @Bean
 public KStream<KEY, VALUE> ssStreams(StreamsBuilder builder) {



        KStream<KEY, VALUE> memberKStream = builder.stream(topicClass.getTopicName());

            KStream stream = memberKStream.map((key, value) -> {
                log.info("Consuming key  :::" + key.toString());


                if(value.getItem ='X' )
                {
                    // need to stop this consumer as soon as this condition is true
                   // jump the application to different class of project 

                }            

           }

}
```

Thing I have tried :
1. Creating a exception and handling via DeserializationExceptionHandler .

Answer (score 0):

You should stop Kafka listener container

Comment: not using the base template @kafkaListener , using Kstream to consume messages